# Tool settings not showing when calling an operation from a pie menu

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

First, I have no actual coding experience, just spend alot of time following guides, and googling/editing.

So I have a basic pie menu script that runs bevel, Relax, and smooth vertices in edit mode. The only thing not working right is Smooth vertices. At first it waited for me to click somewhere and then did nothing.
I figured out(I think) that's because it defaults to Factor=0 and wait_for_input=true.
Ok so after searching, I found that defining an operator was the way to fix it.(no idea if that's the right term) so now I have it set to run  bpy.ops.mesh.vertices_smooth(factor=0.5)

Ok cool, but now the issue is while it runs, it doesn't show the tool settings panel thing, even tho running it from the context menu, and the vertex menu, does  make the settings show. And I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Any Help is appreciated.
Heres the terrible cobbled together script.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu, Operator

# spawn an edit mode selection pie (run while object is in edit mode to get a valid output)

bl_info = {
    "name": "pie mesh edit",
    "author": "Ryuko Reiakuma <RyukoReiakuma@gmail.com>",
    "version": (1, 1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 92, 0),
    "location": "Viewport",
    "description": "edit Pie menus.",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "3d view"}


class VIEW3D_MT_PIE_specials(Menu):
    # label is displayed at the center of the pie menu.
    bl_label = "Specials"
    bl_idname = "mesh.specials"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        # operator_enum will just spread all available options
        # for the type enum of the operator on the pie
        #pie.operator_enum("mesh.select_mode", "type")
        pie.operator("vertices.smooth")
        pie.operator("mesh.bevel")
        pie.operator("mesh.relax")
        #this used to work, but now it just does nothing after you click.
        pie.operator("mesh.vertices_smooth")

class VerticesSmooth(Operator):
    bl_idname = "vertices.smooth"
    bl_label = "VerticesSmooth"
    
    def execute(self, context): 
        bpy.ops.mesh.vertices_smooth(factor=0.5)

        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_MT_PIE_specials)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VerticesSmooth)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name="Mesh")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", "Q", "PRESS").properties.name="mesh.specials"

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_MT_PIE_specials)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VerticesSmooth)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="VIEW3D_MT_PIE_specials")
```